# Can I add a CSS class definition to the Html.LabelFor in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I hope someone out there has some ideas. I would like to tidy up my code and so I already used the Html.LabelFor. However now I want to assign a CSS class to the labels.

```
Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.Description   ????)
```

Does anyone out there know if this is possible in MVC3. Note it's MVC3 I am using. Already I saw a post that talked about MVC2 and there being no simple solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this in MVC 3. You will have to write your helper that does this. Take a look at the `LabelExtensions` class to see how it is done.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted some confirmation there was nothing new in MVC3. I wonder why they didn't give the Html.LabelFor a bit more flexibility. I guess I'm not the only one wanting to do this.

Comment: @LeeGarner well, i'm on the MVC team and I'm not sure why the Label helper does not take a `htmlAttributes` parameter. Perhaps some oversight. I'll file a bug to make sure we add it in the next version.

Comment: @marcind while you're at it, can you un-internal the helpers, ie. in LabelExtensions, LabelHelper is internal, so we can't use it when rolling our own helper extensions.

Comment: @George R - it's unlikely they'll do that.  They intern them for a reason, and that's so that people don't do what you want to do.  That frees them to change the implementation from version to version without worrying about compatibility with end user apps.

Comment: @George R - the next version of MVC will support a `htmlAttributes` parameter like all the other helpers to enable this scenario. We probably won't be making the `LabelHelper` function public though. But I hope this will meet your needs.

Comment: Just for the sake of anybody reading this now, MVC4 allows the htmlAttributes parameter, which solves this.

Answer (score 15):

Here you go buddy-o:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
  using System;
  using Collections.Generic;
  using Linq;
  using Linq.Expressions;
  using Mvc;

  public static class LabelExtensions
  {
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
      return html.LabelFor(expression, null, htmlAttributes);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
      return html.LabelHelper(
            ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData),
            ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression),
            HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes),
            labelText);
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString LabelHelper(this HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, string htmlFieldName, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, string labelText = null)
    {
      var str = labelText
            ?? (metadata.DisplayName
            ?? (metadata.PropertyName
            ?? htmlFieldName.Split(new[] { '.' }).Last()));

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

      var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
      tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
      tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
      tagBuilder.SetInnerText(str);

      return tagBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString(this TagBuilder tagBuilder, TagRenderMode renderMode)
    {
      return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(renderMode));
    }
  }
}
```