# No overload for method 'Label' takes 3 arguments

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, overloading

I am using ASP.Net MVC 3, have referenced all the proper DLLs (see included screenshots), but for some reason I get a this compilation error.

[image: Method Signature]

[image: Web.config Assemblies]

[image: Compilation Error]

Comment: this might sound pretty basic but have you tried do a clean and then a rebuild? also do you get the same error in a brand new project?

Comment: @keshav, I always clean and rebuild. And yes, it does happen in a brand new ASP.Net MVC 3 project.

Comment: to me that seems like there is a problem with your installation. you can try to reinstall ...

Comment: @keshav, I just reinstalled and even forced the app to copy the assemblies to the bin folder, same issue. It also happens in multiple environments. Does this not happen for you?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922075/can-i-add-a-css-class-definition-to-the-html-labelfor-in-mvc3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was an odd occurrence. I was able to reproduce your error. I was also able to figure out why it was happening and how to bypass it.

**Why It Occurs**

There is a namespace collision between [`System.Web.Mvc.Html`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453858(v=vs.108).aspx) and [`System.Web.WebPages.Html`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538318(v=vs.111).aspx)

**What the result of the collision was**

*System.Web.Mvc.Html*

This namespace holds a definition for the method

`LabelExtensions.Label (HtmlHelper, String, String)`

As you will notice, this is the namespace which takes precedent and causes the problem. It has only two overloads. `(String)` or `(String, String)`. While testing, this was the only option which showed up.

---

**How to bypass it**

What you really wanted was this namespace

*System.Web.WebPages.Html*

This namespace holds a definition for the method

`HtmlHelper.Label (String, String, IDictionary<String, Object>)`

You can now see that the availability to add `new { @class = "myClass" }` is present.

**Create your own instance**

Get your own `HtmlHelper` and bypass the `LabelExtension` like this:

*razor*

```
@{
 var h = new System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper();
}
```

*asp*

```
<% var h = new System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper(); %>
```

Make sure that this is not nested inside of a razor or `<%=` block because it will prevent it from being available. It needs to be at the global level of the page.

**Use the correct label**

Now you may use this:

*razor*

`@h.Label("firstName", "First Name", new { @class = "control-label" })`

*asp*

`<%= h.Label("firstName", "First Name", new { @class = "control-label" }) %>`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have picked an overload from *Asp.Net Mvc 4*, and then the compiler complains because it doesn't exist in *Asp.Net Mvc 3*.

Check out these links to see the `Html.Label(...)` overloads in different versions of Asp.Net Mvc:

[Asp.Net Mvc 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[Asp.Net Mvc 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)
[Asp.Net Mvc 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Based on the info in the linked pages, it seems like your Visual Studio (for some reason) is giving you Intellisense based on *Asp.Net Mvc 4*, but when the page is supposed to be compiled Mvc version 3 is used and the overload you have chosen does not exist.

Not sure why VS is giving Intellisense from version 4 though...

Comment: That looks correct, but I don't have MVC 4 installed. I'm using VS2010 and .net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `~/Views/Web.config`

See if there's `configuration/system.web/pages/namespaces` node

Try to add `<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>` in there.

The Label method is in the above namespace. Looks like your view doesn't find it.

Since you don't compile views, it builds just fine. Also, your intellisense is getting the method just fine from the references. However, it's almost like if your view isn't getting the method on runtime.

While adding the aforementioned namespace into the web.config MAY fix the issue, it hides a potentially larger problem in your application. The "fix" should give a starting point for you to debug the situation further.

If this fixes your issue, try comparing your web.config files against a completely new and untouched MVC project. See what you got differently which may prevent the views from finding the Html Helper.

Comment: It is in the Views/Web.Config  Other `Html.Label()` methods work, just not this one.

Comment: And the other Html.Label() instances have the same signature?

Comment: No, this is the only 3 parameter signature, the other is 2 - no `object htmlAttributes`

Comment: Can you klick your cursor to the .Label method in the view and press F12 to see from which assembly and namespace visual studio picks that overload from? That could help you identify which namespace to add into the web config.

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception because you're trying to use an `HtmlExtension` which doesn't exist in ASP.NET MVC3 by default. You need to add HTML attribute support to `Html.Label()`.

Basically you need to add your own extension methods for `HtmlHelper`. You can start with MVC3 source code. Add this class:

```
public static class MyLabelExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, string expression,
        string labelText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return Label(html, expression, labelText, 
                        new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper html, string expression,
        string labelText, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        return LabelHelper(html,
          ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(expression, html.ViewData),
          expression, labelText, htmlAttributes);
    }

    // added htmlAttributes to the default MVC implementation
    internal static MvcHtmlString LabelHelper(HtmlHelper html,
        ModelMetadata metadata, string htmlFieldName,
        string labelText = null,
        IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        string str = labelText;
        if (str == null)
        {
            string displayName = metadata.DisplayName;
            if (displayName == null)
            {
                string propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
                if (propertyName == null)
                    str = Enumerable.Last(
                        htmlFieldName.Split(
                            new[]
                                {
                                    '.'
                        }));
                else
                    str = propertyName;
            }
            else
                str = displayName;
        }
        string innerText = str;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText))
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(
            html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(
            htmlFieldName)));

        // this differs from MVC3 source code:
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(innerText);

        // this is different too:
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

After you've added these extension methods you can use them in you views like this:

```
<%= Html.Label("firstName", "First Name", new { @class = "control-label" }) %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
 <%=Html.Label("firstname","First Name",new {@class="control-label"})%>
```

try using following:

**IN RAZOR:**

```
   @Html.Label( "firstname", "First Name" ,new {  @class = "control-label" });
```

But, I would personally recommend you not doing this. If you have a model and you are taking first name from it then you could use that as below:

```
   @Html.Label( model=>model.FirstName, "First Name" ,new {  @class = "control-label" });
```

**IN ASPX VIEW ENGINE:**

```
  <%=Html.Label(model=>model.FirstName,"First Name",new {@class="control-label"})%>
```

Be sure to add your current model in the view page as below:

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Project.Models.Whatever>" %>
```

Comment: I'm not using Rzor, the `@` code doesn't work for Aspx render engine.

Comment: The page already has a model that is being used, thus I cannot use another model. And besides that, my question isn't how to bind a model (and the proper method is `LabelFor`). It is how to fix my error.

Comment: @JeremyBoyd: Can't you see the parameters to the method in your given screenshot? Clearly , they say to add an expression like I have done...

Comment: Look closer at the parameters, it is a string type parameter.